# How python pymysql.cursors get INOUT return result from mysql stored procedure

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, stored-procedures

I have mysql proc:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mysproc`(INOUT  par_a INT(10), IN  par_b VARCHAR(255) , IN  par_c VARCHAR(255), IN  par_etc VARCHAR(255))
    BEGIN
        // bla... insert query here
        SET par_a = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

to test that sp, if i run:

```
SET @par_a = -1;
SET @par_b = 'one';
SET @par_c = 'two';
SET @par_etc = 'three';

CALL mysproc(@par_a, @par_b, @par_c, @par_etc);
SELECT @par_a;
COMMIT;
```

it return @par_a as what i want - so i assume my db is fine...

then...

I have python as follow:

```
import pymysql.cursors

def someFunction(self, args):
        # generate Query
        query = "SET @par_a = %s; \
            CALL mysproc(@par_a, %s, %s, %s); \
            SELECT @par_a \
            commit;"

        try:
            with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query,(str(par_a), str(par_b), str(par_c), str(par_etc)))
                self.connection.commit()
                result = cursor.fetchone()
                print(result) # <-- it print me 'none' how do i get my @par_a result from mysproc above?
                return result
        except:
            raise
        finally:
            self.DestroyConnection()
```

result: the stored proc executed, as i can see record in.

problem: but i cant get my @par_a result in my python code from mysproc above?

and, if i change:

```
# generate Query
query = "SET @par_a = '" + str(-1) + "'; \
    CALL mysproc(@par_a, %s, %s, %s); \
    SELECT @par_a \
    commit;"
```

to

```
# generate Query
query = "SELECT 'test' \
    commit;"
```

and

```
cursor.execute(query)
```

strangely, it give me the correct result `('test',)`

Comment: You use `cursor.fetchall()` or `cursor.fetchone()`. You should take a little time to read the documentation here: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks,@Nicarus , 
do i need to do 'select' in my query variable in python in order to get the par_a result? or fetchone() will smart enough to get my par_a result? so far i tried, python print me 'none' T_T

Comment: You need to have the query return the value(s) you want. Once the query is written to do so, you use the fetch functions to return that result in Python.

Comment: @Nicarus, not work, i have update my question and change to your sample doc, but result keep sending me 'none'

Comment: Why are you writing your query above differently than the one below???

Comment: sorry i missed the "select" statment - question updated.
basically, it's the same with above query - and i confirm the insert statement is executed in stored proc, just the out param is not catch-ed by python. and why i change, just to test to follow your doc as close as much

Answer (score 0):

I used this class and I got response.

```
import pymysql.cursors

class connMySql:
        def __init__(self, User, Pass, DB, Host='localhost', connShowErr=False, connAutoClose=True):
                self.ShowErr = connShowErr
                self.AutoClose = connAutoClose
                self.DBName = DB
                try:
                        self.connection = pymysql.connect(host=Host,
                             user=User,
                             password=Pass,
                             db=DB, #charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
                except ValueError as ValErr:
                        if self.ShowErr == True: print(ValErr)
                        return False

        def Fetch(self, Query):
                try:
                        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
                                # Read a single record
                                cursor.execute(Query)
                                result = cursor.fetchall()
                        return result
                except ValueError as ValErr:
                        if self.ShowErr == True: print(ValErr)
                        return False
                finally:
                        if self.AutoClose == True: self.connection.close()

        def Insert(self, Query):
                try:
                        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
                                # Create a new record
                                cursor.execute(Query)
                        # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
                        # your changes.
                        self.connection.commit()
                except ValueError as ValErr:
                        if self.ShowErr == True: print(ValErr)
                        return False
                finally:
                        if self.AutoClose == True: self.connection.close()

        def ProcedureExist(self, ProcedureName):
                try:
                        result = self.Fetch("SELECT * FROM mysql.proc WHERE db = \"" + str(self.DBName) + "\";")
                        Result = []
                        for item in result:
                                Result.append(item['name'])
                        if ProcedureName in Result:
                                return True
                        else:
                                return False
                except ValueError as ValErr:
                        if self.ShowErr == True: print(ValErr)
                        return False

        def CallProcedure(ProcedureName, Arguments=""):
                try:
            # Set arguments as a string value
                        result = self.Fetch('CALL ' + ProcedureName + '(' + Arguments + ')')
                except ValueError as ValErr:
                        if self.ShowErr == True: print(ValErr)
                        return False
                finally:
                        if self.AutoClose == True: self.connection.close()

        def CloseConnection(self):
                try:
                        self.connection.close()
                        return True
                except ValueError as ValErr:
                        if self.ShowErr == True: print(ValErr)
                        return False

def main():
    objMysqlConn = connMySql('user', '1234', 'myDB', connShowErr=True, connAutoClose=False)
    ProcedureName= "mysproc"
    if objMysqlConn.ProcedureExist(ProcedureName):
            result = objMysqlConn.Fetch('CALL ' + ProcedureName + '()')
            if result != False:
                    result = result[0]
                    print(result)
    else:
            print("The procecure does not exist!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```